# Selenium - frame issue with google forms

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Would appreciate a help with selenium.

Trying to fill in google form for several entries, so that I need to input the feirst row a df, than click "Submit" a new form and run again for the second form and to the n-th row.

Got stuck with `NoSuchFrameException: Unable to locate frame with index`   error after the first entry. Read on Selenium docs that one can locate a window's frame in console and it gives me nothing (F12 --> find frame (any combination tried) --> no matches). No such thing in google form (or my search is wrong hands down)

Haven't got anything on the issue so tried `frame(0)` - no luck.

Any tips would be appreciated. The whole code is below

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.firefox_binary import FirefoxBinary
import time
import pandas as pd

options = Options()
options.binary_location = FirefoxBinary(r"C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe")

driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=r'C:\WebDriver\bin\geckodriver.exe', firefox_options=options)

driver.implicitly_wait(10)

reg = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\User\Desktop\Form.csv', header=0, delimiter=';', sep=r'\s*;\s*')

reg_2 = reg.values.tolist()

driver.get('https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSd9FQ33H5SMHelf9O1jjHl7FtLTtaTdFuC4dUFv-educaFiJA/viewform?vc=0&c=0&w=1&flr=0&gxids=7628')

try: 
    for row in reg_2:
        element_count = 0
   
          
        for element in range(len(row)):
            first = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div/div[2]/form/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/input")
            last = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div/div[2]/form/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/input")
            mail =  driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div/div[2]/form/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[3]/div/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/input")
            last.send_keys(row[0])
            first.send_keys(row[1])
            mail.send_keys(row[2])
            submit = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="mG61Hd"]/div[2]/div/div[3]/div[1]/div/div/span/span')
            submit.click()
            time.sleep(3)
            
            element_count +=1
            driver.switch_to.frame(0)
            driver.switch_to.default_content()
finally:
    driver.quit()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
driver.switch_to.frame(0)
driver.switch_to.default_content()
```

remove this two line of code that google form doesn't have any iframe in it

if you want to submit agian click the submit another response link:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//a[contains(text(),"Submit another response")]').click()
```

Comment: No, it does not work, I tried this before, after returning to the main form the code cannot find the Xpath, it is a quite common problem.

Comment: what you are intending to do ? there is no iframe in that page. After going to main page add a explicit wait to wait for elements to load properly

Comment: Explicit wait is already there, you can see it in the code. I have no idea so far

Answer (score 0):

Well, in fact after deleting the old form and starting anew the thing worked in the end. Had to change several other elements. Also added password  and password_confirm field:

```
while len(reg_2) > element_count:
     try:      
        
          for row in reg_2:
            first = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div/div[2]/form/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/input")
            last = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div/div[2]/form/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/input")
            mail =  driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div/div[2]/form/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[3]/div/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/input")
            password = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div/div[2]/form/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[4]/div/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/input')
            password_confirm = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div/div[2]/form/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[5]/div/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/input')
        
            last.send_keys(row[0])
            first.send_keys(row[1])
            mail.send_keys(row[2])
            password.send_keys(row[3])
            password_confirm.send_keys(row[3])
            
            submit = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="mG61Hd"]/div[2]/div/div[3]/div[1]/div/div/span/span')
            submit.click()
            time.sleep(3)
            element_count +=1
            #driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[4]/a').click()
            driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.freebirdFormviewerViewResponseLinksContainer > a:nth-child(1)').click()
   
     finally:
         driver.quit()
```